# Does systems (such as the cell) far from equilibrium have to dissipate their energy? Can't they store it? Is there a physical requirement for that?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, non-equilibrium

It is a well known fact in the field of non-equilibrium statistical physics that in order to maintain a system far from equilbrium, you need to drive it via an external energy source. The system uses that energy to go to a non-equilibrium state and then disspates some of that energy in the form of a heat to go back to an equilibrium state. By driving the system in this way, one can maintain the system in far from equilibrium.

However, why does the system have to dissipate the energy in the form of a heat? For example, the cell uses the very same mechanism to keep itself alive; it uses ATP to maintain its non-equilibrium state and function. But, wouldn't it be more "clever" to store that extra energy somewhere, instead of dissipating as a heat? Is there any physical explanation why do these kind of systems dissipate these extra energy?

Comment: I mean, don't we actually do that already? We store the food we eat as fat and carbohydrates. ATP, NADPH are molecules which can be made to run in chemical reactions and release heat.

Comment: The only requirement that the system must fulfill (after getting isolated) is the second law of thermodynamics. Entropy should increase or stay the same. A way of doing so is dissipating energy via the vibration of atoms or radiation since these processes increase a lot the entropy because "they are very hard to track."

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I mean you can create systems which do that. Just, generally, things break a bit.

So for example, if you are the sort of person who likes to eat things, you probably eat a variety of things. It turns out that except for “chalk candy”—the right-handed version of glucose known as dextrose—your cells cannot use these various foods for energy directly, but so they have to be forwarded to your liver to make the conversion, and your liver makes the dextrose. Then it links those dextrose molecules into hairballs called glycogen for slightly longer-term storage and normally if you have too much glycogen your liver starts making droplets of fat and sending them off to the fat cells. This has one of those Latin names that literally describes it so as to make it sound very fancy and academic, “hepatic de-novo lipogenesis” rather than “livery new-fat-making.”

Obviously, your body can store a lot of fat. What happens as it stores more fat? Well, you need more adipose tissue to store and maintain the fat so that you can retrieve it later. This requires more cells, more blood vessels, all that. The organism becomes bigger and it requires more of your basal metabolism just to keep everything functioning, until your daily caloric expenditure is equal to your daily intake. Viewed this way, a physicist does not necessarily want you to eat less and exercise more, because if you just do that for a finite time and then return to your old habits, you're going to return to the exact same equilibrium. A physicist would prefer that you change your relationship with food, you change how you listen to yourself: I know that sounds like psychology but those “driving mechanisms” and “feedback mechanisms” are extremely important to analyzing any complex system.

Like, with linear systems, if I know that you have built a circuit out of resistors and capacitors and inductors and batteries and current sources, and you tell me that you're going to increase some battery voltage over here, I can immediately tell you that there will be proportionately more current and voltage loss across this resistor over there. But the moment you start throwing in transistors or op-amps or diodes or other nonlinear components, that sort of reasoning goes out the window. Your added voltage now reverse-biases a diode that was forward-biased, so the resistor downstream of that diode does not increase in current; the current actually goes to zero. Complex systems don't work by easy rules, and the tendency for everything to eventually come to an equilibrium is kind of the most beautiful thing about applied physics because it lets us cut out so much theory.

Returning back to the body, some people have “glycogen storage diseases” where they can store glycogen, but they can't digest it for whatever reason. The liver gets larger and larger with glycogen; in many kids the first sign is a swollen belly. Maybe surprisingly, glycogen is so non-toxic that treatment is generally focused on replacing what the glycogen was supposed to do—keeping blood sugar up—rather than dealing with the enlarged liver. I don't know exactly what limits the accumulation of glycogen after that, so I assume it does not grow totally without bound, but presumably you eventually start to excrete glycogen when you go to the bathroom or some other process breaks it apart. If nothing else, you do constantly have to recycle cells and the old dead cells need to get flushed out and they probably carry glycogen away with them.

But yeah, basically the problem with storing things endlessly (because you do not want *waste*) is that it requires space to store the thing, and that generally creates some form or another of *clutter*, and usually clutter eventually causes other forms of waste. A related revolution happened in manufacturing, where the very low overheads drove companies to do the “just increase the voltage” thing of having expediters and managers who tell employees “don’t just slack off, do something!” and a lot of companies then had these very chaotic factories where there was a ton of work-in-process sitting in various states of half-finished-ness sitting out on the factory floor cluttering up the space. It wasn't a linear system! Trying to eliminate one form of waste by trading it for storage created another form of waste.

Bottom line is, you have only a couple choices. You either have to build a really big reservoir that you are throwing droplets of water into, so that you are not worried over the lifetime of the system that some resource is finite; or you have a smaller reservoir and you face waste when it overflows, or you have a “backpressure” mechanism to limit inputs when storage is full. These trends happen for any complex system which can store things.